# Dynamic tab content in primefaces using ui:include not working

Tags: jsf, primefaces, facelets

I'm unable to use ui:include in tabView. I'm trying to make dynamic tabs using included Facelet.

Here's my code:

```
<p:tabView id="panelGl" var="tabContent" value="#{mainPageBackingBean.tabs}" widgetVar="panelGlJs" style="height: 100%;" dynamic="true" >
            <p:ajax event="tabClose" listener="#{mainPageController.onTabClose}" oncomplete="questionDialogWV.show()" update="@(this) :questionForm:questionFormPanel" />
            <p:ajax event="tabChange" onstart="setActive()" update="@(this)" />         
            <p:tab title="#{tabContent.title}" titletip="#{tabContent.description}" closable="true">
                <ui:include src="#{mainPageBackingBean.tabContents}" />
            </p:tab>
</p:tabView>
```

And `#{mainPageBackingBean.tabContents}` runtime value is pointing at this Facelet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
 xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
 xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
 xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
 xmlns:fn="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions"
 xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
 <p:panel>
    <h:form> 
        <p:commandButton id="testEmail" value="" process="@this" actionListener="#{communicationChannelsController.testEmailChannel()}"/>
    </h:form>
 </p:panel>
</ui:composition>
```

When I use the above `ui:include` outside of `p:tabView` it works normally (I am able to invoke `communicationChannelsController.testEmailChannel()` without a problem). Also when I copy the contents of above file inside `p:tab` everything works fine also.

Problem is that, when combined `p:tab` and `ui:include` do not work, this bean method is not called.

What is the best approach at creating dynamic tabs using some navigation bean like `mainPageBackingBean` in my example?

Comment: which version of JSF and Primefaces are u using??

Comment: I'm not using any version anymore and I'm very happy with that :) I think it was one of the 3.4.x versions.